# Explanation for the ending of John Wick 3

Tags: ending, john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum

In the middle of *John Wick: Chapter 3 - Parabellum* John is roaming the desert in search of the 'Elder one'. He then proceeds to make a deal with the 'Elder one' to revoke his excommunicado status and in return he agrees to

> kill Winston.

However, towards the end of the movie we see that John Wick doesn't do so. So what happens to John Wick for disobeying the elder one?

Comment: I removed your other 2 questions about the workings of the Outfit, since these sites work by asking individual questions. You could still ask them as separate questions (the text is also still available in this post's revision history). Though, they might be a litte too broad to be answerable satisfyingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He didn't kill Winston, so officially he's still excommunicado, although given that

> Winston shot him, and he fell off the roof.

The High Table may well believe he is dead and pursue him no further.  This of course leaves a nice opening for *John Wick 4*.